# My nodejs table is returning empty and there are data in the table

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

My program is suppose to get order information from the order, but its not getting the information in the table, when I ask to print it, it just prints the table empty. And when I look into the DataBase and View Data on the table, it saved some data

```
router.get('/order', function (req, res, next) {
if (req.query.key == API_KEY) {
    req.getConnection(function (error, conn) {
        var order_fbid = req.query.orderFBID
        if (order_fbid != null) {
            conn.query('SELECT orderId,orderFBID,orderPhone,orderName,orderAddress,orderStatus,orderDate,'
                + 'restaurantId,transactionId,'
                + 'CASE WHEN cod=1 THEN \'TRUE\' ELSE \'FALSE\' END as cod,'
                + 'totalPrice,numOfItem FROM `order` WHERE orderFBID =? AND numOfItem > 0'
                + ' ORDER BY orderId DESC', [order_fbid], function (err, rows, fields) {

                    if (err) {
                        res.status(500)
                        res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: err.message }))
                    }
                    else {
                        if (rows.length > 0) {
                            res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: true, result: rows }))
                        }
                        else {
                            res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "Empty111" }))
                        }
                    }
                })

        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "Missing restaurantId in query" }))
        }

    })
}
else {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "Wrong orderFBID key marfe" }))
}
})
```

Comment: What do you get by running this query into a client?

Comment: you could enable logging in mysql and see what reaches the server.